# Vuejs b-table array template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I want to create a b-table template can understand data type and if it is array then it shows array keys one under the other. For example:

data.item.value may be :

- string
- array
- json

```
<b-table :items="mydata"> 

<template #cell(name)="data"> 

  <b-list-group-item>
  {{data.item.value}}
  </b-list-group-item>

</template>
</b-table>
```

if data.item.value is array should open new b-list-group-item automatically:

```
first b-list-group-item :  data.item.value[0].name
second b-list-group-item :  data.item.value[1].name
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `v-for` on the array inside your template.  Then you can use `v-if` to special case type inside the `group-item`.

```
<b-table :items="mydata"> 
  <template #cell="data"> 
    <b-list-group-item v-for='value of data.item.value'>
      {{value.name}}
    </b-list-group-item> 
  </template>
</b-table>
```